# SMART with Megaraid under windows

Tags: windows, smart, megaraid

Is there a way to read RAW HDD SMART value that is behind a MegaRaid raid?

apparently that is possible with smartmontools under linux, is there something similar possible with windows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it's not possible: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki/Supported_RAID-Controllers - they've added Areca cards last time.